# Error building KIdleTime with kdesrc-build

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, ubuntu-22.04

I followed this [tutorial](https://community.kde.org/Get_Involved/development#KDE_Frameworks) of KDE and I got a problem when building KDE Frameworks with `kdesrc-build` (I'm building it on Linux Ubuntu):

`kdesrc-build frameworks --ignore-modules kdewebkit`

But when It's building the frameworks, It built failed and stopped at the package called `KIdleTime`. I also tried building it from scratch with the command:

`kdesrc-build KIdleTime --refresh-build`

But this still not work.

Here's the building log (build with CMake):

```
# kdesrc-build running: 'cmake' '-B' '.' '-S' '/home/hien/kde/src/kidletime' '-G' 'Unix Makefiles' '-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=ON' '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo' '-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=-pipe' '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/hien/kde/usr'
# from directory: /home/hien/kde/build/kidletime
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- 

Installing in /home/hien/kde/usr. Run /home/hien/kde/build/kidletime/prefix.sh to set the environment for KIdleTime.
-- Looking for __GLIBC__
-- Looking for __GLIBC__ - found
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_DATE_TIME
-- Performing Test HAVE_DATE_TIME - Success
-- Performing Test BSYMBOLICFUNCTIONS_AVAILABLE
-- Performing Test BSYMBOLICFUNCTIONS_AVAILABLE - Success
-- Found X11: /usr/include   
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Found XCB_XCB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so (found version "1.14") 
-- Found XCB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so (found version "1.14") found components: XCB 
-- Found XCB_SYNC: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so (found version "1.14") 
-- Found XCB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so (found version "1.14") found components: XCB SYNC 
-- Found X11_XCB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so (found version "1.7.5") 
-- Found QtWaylandScanner: /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qtwaylandscanner  
-- Found Wayland_Client: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so (found version "1.20.0") 
-- Found Wayland: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so (found suitable version "1.20.0", minimum required is "1.9") found components: Client 
-- Could NOT find WaylandProtocols: Found unsuitable version "1.25", but required is at least "1.27" (found //usr/share/wayland-protocols)
-- Warning: Property URL already set to "https://wayland.freedesktop.org/", overriding it with "https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/wayland-protocols/"
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_VISIBILITY
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_VISIBILITY - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_INLINE_VISIBILITY
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_HIDDEN_INLINE_VISIBILITY - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR
-- Performing Test COMPILER_HAS_DEPRECATED_ATTR - Success
-- The following features have been enabled:

 * libXext, required for X-Sync based poller
 * libX11-xcb, required for X-Sync based poller
 * libxcb, required for X-Sync based poller
 * libxcb-sync, required for X-Sync based poller
 * X-Sync based poller, efficient operation of KIdleTime. STRONGLY RECOMMENDED (requires libXext, libX11-xcb, libxcb and libxcb-sync)
 * X-Screensaver based poller, KIdleTime fallback mode (libXss)

-- The following OPTIONAL packages have been found:

 * X11
 * Qt5WaylandClient (required version >= 5.15.2)
 * XCB, X protocol C-language Binding, <https://xcb.freedesktop.org/>
 * X11_XCB, A compatibility library for code that translates Xlib API calls into XCB calls, <https://xorg.freedesktop.org/>

-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * ECM (required version >= 5.106.0), Extra CMake Modules., <https://commits.kde.org/extra-cmake-modules>
 * Qt5Gui
 * Qt5X11Extras
 * Qt5DBus
 * Qt5 (required version >= 5.15.2)
 * QtWaylandScanner, Executable that converts XML protocol files to C++ code, <https://qt.io/>
 * Wayland (required version >= 1.9), C library implementation of the Wayland protocol: a protocol for a compositor to talk to its clients, <https://wayland.freedesktop.org/>
 * PlasmaWaylandProtocols (required version >= 1.6.0)
 * WaylandScanner, Executable that converts XML protocol files to C code, <https://wayland.freedesktop.org/>

-- The following features have been disabled:

 * QCH, API documentation in QCH format (for e.g. Qt Assistant, Qt Creator & KDevelop)

-- The following REQUIRED packages have not been found:

 * WaylandProtocols (required version >= 1.27), Specifications of extended Wayland protocols, <https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/wayland-protocols/>
   Collection of Wayland protocols that add functionality not available in the Wayland core protocol

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FeatureSummary.cmake:464 (message):
  feature_summary() Error: REQUIRED package(s) are missing, aborting CMake
  run.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:134 (feature_summary)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/hien/kde/build/kidletime/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

As you see in the log, `WaylandProtocols` version 1.27 is required (But I'm using 1.25) so I tried upgrading `WaylandProtocols` with the command:

`sudo apt upgrade wayland-protocols`.

But here's how it said to me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
wayland-protocols is already the newest version (1.25-1). # Look at this
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ffmpegthumbs kdegraphics-thumbnailers kimageformat-plugins libavif13
  libdolphinvcs5 libgav1-0 libkf5kdcraw5 libkf5kexiv2-15.0.0 libyuv0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  python2.7-minimal libimage-magick-perl libpostproc-dev imagemagick
  libavcodec-extra libopusfile0 libjs-jquery-ui libopenexr-dev libavdevice58
  libopenexr25 libmagick++-6.q16-8 libpostproc55 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra
  libswscale-dev libavdevice-dev libimage-magick-q16-perl
  libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libavcodec-extra58 libavutil56 imagemagick-6.q16
  libswscale5 libeditorconfig0 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 libavutil-dev
  libswresample3 imagemagick-6-common libavfilter-dev libavformat58
  libopusfile-dev python2.7 libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libswresample-dev libavfilter7
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`wayland-protocols` 1.25 is currently the newest version?

Even more, I tried installing `wayland-protocols` version 1.27 using this command:
`sudo apt install wayland-protocols=1.27`

But:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package wayland-protocols is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Version '1.27' for 'wayland-protocols' was not found
```

So, the main problem here is not like the title, the actual problem I've got here is **How to install Wayland Protocols version 1.27?**
(Linux Ubuntu 22.04.2)

Comment: I believe your main problem looks to be: `Could NOT find WaylandProtocols: Found unsuitable version "1.25", but required is at least "1.27" (found //usr/share/wayland-protocols)` which is related to your package manager / distribution.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But I can't install WaylandProtocols version 1.27. You can learn more about my updated question. Thanks!

Comment: This probably amounts to either upgrading ubuntu to [23.04](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2023/04/upgrade-to-ubuntu-23-04) or this: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112157/how-can-i-install-more-recent-versions-of-software-than-what-debian-provides](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112157/how-can-i-install-more-recent-versions-of-software-than-what-debian-provides)